# ECSlidingViewController crash when showing modal view controller from a topViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, xcode5, ecslidingviewcontroller

XCode 5, `iOS7` project, using `Storyboard`, but mostly to define the flow, no `UI` is created by it.

I have this scenario (sorry for no screenshot, but the storyboard is actually pretty big):

I've setup `ECSlidingViewController` as it should. It's initial `VC` (the subclass of `ECSlidingViewController`) is `rootVC` and inside him I define the under `ViewController` and top `ViewController`.

I have `UITableVC` with embed in `UINavigationVC` as underLeftViewController. As my topViewController I have `UITabbarVC` with three tabs. Each of the `childVC` of the `Tabbar` has its own `navigationBar` a button which opens the side menu (underLeftViewController).

In one of my tabs I have `UITableVC` with embed in `UINavigationVC`. Lets call this one **Screen1**.

When pressed on some row I push `PSCollectionView` (collectionView with customisable cell). A grid displaying image thumbnails. Lets call this one **Screen2**.

When pressed on some image, I push fullscreen image. This one is **Screen3**.

There is a button which when pressed it presents a `modalVC` with embed in `UINavigationVC` which present image details.

Now when I dismiss the `modalVC` I'm back on **Screen3**. Then I press back and from **Screen3** i go back to **Screen2** successfully, but then when i press back once again to navigate to **Screen1** (first tab of the `tabbarVC` where the side menu button is) the app crushes with this error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UnderViewController _mainContext]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa640610'
```

I can't find what actually is happening. I don't even try to reach UnderViewController (even if I want I can't - no button to display it). Searched on the Internet for some solution, but nothing. Seems like I'm the only one with this problem, so I must be doing something wrong.

Just to mention, in underLeftViewController when selected row from different section I present `modalVC` which when i dismiss it, the app is still functioning without problem. The problem arise only in that scenario.

Any tips, suggestions are welcome.